# Is it okay that I'm having warning: in the working copy of ... LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it almost in every file?

Tags: git

As far as I understood, If I work on Windows and want to collaborate with other people who might have Linux or Mac OS, I need to give core.autocrlf a ‘true’ value. And I work on Windows

BUT. In many cases I have this warning. Is it fine or is it a certain red flag?

**UPD:**

The question that I was proposed to check is absoulutely different from my Q. The other question is "Is this warning tail backward?"

I know that I configured the core.autocrlf varibale right because here https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings it's said that on Windows I need to pass a true value.

But maybe there's other problem since I'm seeing the warnings.

Comment: @amphetamachine the question you proposed is completely different from mine

Comment: The answers are relevant for you, though, please read them. It recommends to use false for the autocrlf setting and using a .gitattributes file. It also helps to re-clone the repo (changing the setting obviously does not rewrite potentially lots of files for you).

Comment: @PeterPointer in the answer it's recommended to set core.autocrlf value to false which contradicts to what said here https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings

Comment: @PeterPointer "That way, you avoid any automatic transformation, and can still specify them through a .gitattributes file" specify 'them'. What them? How to specify?
Maybe that's a language barrier, because I don't get what to specify. Could you please help me out with this one?

Comment: @PeterPointer I'm still a starter in git, I just started using it, so I may still not understand many things

Comment: Just search documentation about those on the internet or other questions on StackOverflow. It's too much to describe here. You can always test on a personal repository to check if the settings are working.

Comment: @PeterPointer I've already tried it, several times. That's why I'm asking, because I searched it up, didn't find anything answering to my Q and now asking here because I've got NOTHING left to do. If it's too much to describe here you can write an answer. If you're that sure that there's an answer, please give me the link and indicate the exact place where the answer is